# Trouble returning decimal after input from user

Tags: python, powershell, floating-point, decimal

I'm working on a number of different ways to use variables in functions, but there is one way I just can't figure out after about an hour of searching the web. I just want the user to be able to enter a decimal number like "23.45" and the program print that exact number. I've tried multiple different ways and I always end up with an error or an integer. I am running this in PowerShell. Here is the piece of code:

```
def person(age, gender):
    print "You are %d years old." % age
    print "You are a %s" % gender

how_old = eval(raw_input("How old are you? "))
age = float(how_old)

person(age, "Male")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what language you are used to, but that is not PowerShell code.

Comment: Sorry, this is python 2.7.

Comment: I wrote this in notepad ++ and I run it in PowerShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
print "You are %d years old." % age
```

to

```
print "You are %g years old." % age
```

By the way, `eval` is not necessary there, the `float`conversion suffices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display *exactly* what the user types then use %s the same way you did the second print statement and then remove the float conversion on line 6.  Using %g or %d will cause it to round to fewer decimal places if someone types in 21.345676543 for example.  Of course, I can't think of any possible reason someone would know their age to that detail but you never know!

I second dlask about not needing eval.

Comment: I see your way works too. I figured using %s would not recognize numbers entered as actual numbers in case I wanted to use math on them later, but I guess that when I put the float function in the age variable, it took care of that. It was the %d that was really holding me back.